# Why can’t I insert an entity twice by using Spring Data Jdbc？

Tags: spring, insert, spring-data-jdbc

my entity:

```
@Table("user")
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long user_id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public Long getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(Long user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

my repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("select * from user where username = :username")
    User findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
}
```

my sql for creating the user table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UINQUE_USERNAME`(`username`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

```
User userForRegister = new User(username, passwordEncoder.encode(password));
userRepository.save(userForRegister)
```

If I execute the line of 'userRepository.save(userForRegister)', I will insert an entity successfully the first time.

But, if I want to insert another user entity with different username, i will get an error:

```
2021-01-08 21:37:38.242  INFO 11180 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.k.centre.controller.UserController     : Failed to execute DbAction.InsertRoot(entity=com.***.***.Entity.User@65bc9ea1, generatedId=null)
```

I can insert it until I delete all the data of user table.
Is there any point I missed?

Comment: Do they have different user names? What is the stack trace you are getting?

Comment: Side note: I recommend sticking to the java conventions for names which includes: No underscore for properties and fields.

Comment: yeah！they have different names.It seems that I solved it~ Just add a annotation of @Column("userId")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that GenerateValue would solve the problem

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long user_id;
```

Also I think you should map your ther fields to database columns using @Column annotation

```
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long user_id;
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
```

Comment: It seems that spring jdbc doesn't have the annotation of @GeneratedValue.

Comment: http://zetcode.com/springboot/crudrepository/
it is part of javax.persistence package

Comment: What dependence should I add？

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2

Comment: It seems that I solved it~
Just add a annotation of @Column("userId").I am so confused that why can I insert one in the first time.

Comment: @ge1mina023 if you solved it by adding an `@Column("userId")` you should make that an answer and accept it. The answer here is most is not the correct answer since `javax.persistence` annotations have no effect on Spring Data JDBC at all.

Comment: Have you noticed the other part of my answer where I state that he should use @Column annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` to your `user_id`. This tells Hibernate that id is generated by your database. You configured your database primary key as autoincrement Column. Take also a look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers).

Comment: It seems that spring jdbc doesn't have the annotation of @GeneratedValue.

Comment: It should be part of the spring data package. I think you should look why you can’t use the annotation. Take your favourite dependency analyser (IntelliJ maven helper is great) and look at the dependency tree for the Java persistence api. It should be somewhere under spring data.

Comment: It seems that I solved it~ Just add a annotation of @Column("userId").I am so confused that why can I insert one in the first time.

Comment: I'm also a bit confused. This should not be possible. maybe you set your id manually at some point. Without an exmaple is further investigation difficult.

Comment: This annotation is not part of Spring Data JDBC, you are confusing it with Spring Data JPA or actually JPA.